How to prove two vectors are parallel given the conservation of the angular momentum
Here I asked two questions regarding a "lemma" that my Professor used to prove Kepler's laws. I will post the summary of the discussion and my doubt also here because I think the matter probably deals with math more than physics now.

If $\vec{F}$ is a central force of center $O$ and it is the only force acting on a point $P$, then the trajectory of $P$ is plane.

This is because $\vec{r}\times m\vec{v} = \vec{r_0} \times m\vec{v_0}$, since the angular momentum $\vec{L^O}$ is a constant of motion for central forces. Therefore the motion must take place on a plane, namely the plane (containing $O$) defined by $\vec{L_0^O} \cdot \vec{r_0}=0$, since $\vec{L_0^O} = \vec{L^O}$ and $\vec{L^O} \perp \vec{r}$ , so $\vec{L^O_0} \perp \vec{r}$ for all time.
In a similar way, maybe using some tools of linear algebra or facts from basic geometry, I'd like to prove that:

If $\vec{r_0} \parallel \vec{v_0}$ then the motion takes place on a straight line.

For example, I would like to see that $\vec{r} \parallel \vec{r_0}$, so that clearly the motion takes place on the straight line parallel to $ \vec{r_0}$.
In principle, all I know is that $\vec{r_0} \parallel \vec{v_0}$ and $\vec{r} \parallel \vec{v}$, since $\vec{L^O_0} = \vec{L^O} = 0$, but I don't see any relation between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r_0}$.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Just down the lagranian, to see this must be true. You can use test potential with only x dependence. (Obviously, set y-dot and z-dot which are conserved to zero)

If you are unconvinced by test potential with x dependence use r dependence setting central potential at r=0 and use spherical $|\dot{\vec{r}}|^2$ which you can find on lagranian wiki if you don’t know it

@EEH could you please provide more details? I have no idea what you mean

Ok, I will write up more detailed answer, but level physics are you taking. I assumed it was lagrangian mech class not intro level general physics. Is this correct? I don't want to give Lagrangian mech answer if you are taking intro class

I studied Lagrangian mechanics and it would be nice to see an explanation from this perspective. Anyway, this was claimed before introducing Lagrangian mechanics so I should be able to find an explanation with basic Newtonian mechanics.

You know that $\vec r\times\vec v$ is a constant vector. If it equals $\vec 0$ at time $t_0$, then it is identically zero, so $\vec r\|\vec v$. Differentiating $\vec r=\lambda\vec v$ tells you that $\vec v$ never changes direction. Thus, $\vec r$ is a (functional) scalar multiple of $\vec v_0$. This says that the trajectory is a subset of a line through the origin.

This is precisely what I was looking for. Can you please explain more the fact that "Differentiating $\vec{r}=\lambda \vec{v}$
tells you that $\vec{v}$
never changes direction."?

You get $\vec v=\vec r{}’ = \lambda’\vec v + \lambda \vec v{}’$, so $\vec v{}’|\vec v$. This implies that $\vec v$ never changes direction. (If you want to argue this rigorously, differentiate $\vec v/|\vec v|$.)

I have just differentiated $\vec v/|\vec v|$ using the fact that $\vec v{}’|\vec v$ and I found out that it is in fact $\vec{0}$. Thank you very much for helping me

You’re most welcome. Keep up the good work learning.

I'll do Lagrangian explanation in spherical. My goal is to explictly calculate equations of motion to demonstrate that clearly the trajectory must move in a line. It's pretty easy to see that your claim is true, so I figured I write the whole calculation out in gory detail, so that you can see explicitly why the intuitive answer is correct and so you can compare it with more elegant solutions provided by others to verify where those come from.
Let the central potential V depend only on r (this is part of def for spherical potential). Thus, the Lagranian is
$\dot{r}^2 + r^2 sin^2(\theta) \dot{\phi}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - V(r)$
It should be obvious That angular momentum is conserved. That is, $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi} = 0$. Since we want case where initial velocity is along radial vector we naturally set initial angular velocity to zero. That is, $\dot{\phi} (0)$, $\dot{ \theta} (0)=0$. Thus, we are left with the Lagranian
$\dot{r}^2 - V(r)$
Thus, we only have equation of motion, and we know that solutions are restricted to line defined by $\hat{r}(0)$ as  $\theta(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ are fixed by initial position.
Edit: The last sentence follows from the solution to the equations of motion for conserved quantities and the fixing of initial angular velocity to zero.

Thanks for your effort, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately this goes beyond my current knowledge, but maybe in the future I will understand more.

No problem. Once you've covered conversed quantities in Lagranian mech you will have seen enough to tackle the derivation with a little work. Feel free to ask follow up questions if you do decide to tackle it in the future.

Thank you! When you say "I'll do Lagrangian explanation in spherical" I guess you mean you are going to use spherical coordinates. Is it right? I have never seen this approach (I have only taken some introductory lectures to Lagrangian Mechanics, as part of a Rational Mechanics course, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question). What is the idea behind it?

Background: In physics, the most common strategy for solving any problem is exploiting symmetry. In the case of classical mechanics (and QM for that matter), the symmetries in question are symmetries in the potential. Famously (see Noether's thm, most basic form should be included in your Lagranian textbook), conserved quantities in mechanics are exactly symmetries.

Yeah we proved Noether's theorem, but I don't get why you used spherical coordinates (?)

@DavideMasi Central potentials are defined as potentials that act radially from one body to another. Thus, in the case of the two body problem, they are the class of the potentials that exhibit spherical symmetry. That is that angular momentum is conserved or equivalently that potential does depends only on radial r and not $\phi$ or $\theta$. Spherical coordinate are thus the natural choice to simplify the problem as I did above using conversation of angular momentum.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
